# Click on link to shared drive in Lotus Notes email, opens in Firefox instead of Windows Explorer

Tags: firefox, email, lotus-notes

I have Windows 7, Lotus Notes 8.5, and I use Firefox as my default browser.  I often will put links to a shared drive in my emails so recipients can easily go straight to the files I am mentioning in my emails.  When I click on them, these open in Firefox and do not work.  When I make my default browser IE and click on the links, they open in Windows Explorer (not Internet Explorer) and work fine.

Is there a setting in Firefox I can change that will stop it from opening these links in emails?

Edited 5/14/14 because I learned more on the situation after making IE my default and seeing everything work fine.

Answer (score 0):

File -> Preferences -> Web Browser . And set to "Use Os default browser". I think that should solve your first issue.

Second issue is solved by clicking on the small "chain link" icon in the tool bar when adding a hyperlink.

Comment: First setting already in place.  Second one, even if I click the chain link and paste in the exact destination I want, as soon as I hit OK, all the \ in the Name stay the same but all the \ in the Link are magically turned into /.